# Build error when trying to deploy Next app with Vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm trying to deploy an app to Vercel and getting this error in the build logs:

```
Running "npm run build"
> next-portfolio@0.1.0 build
> next build
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry
info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
Failed to compile.
./portfolio-2/sanity.cli.ts:1:31
Type error: Cannot find module 'sanity/cli' or its corresponding type declarations.
> 1 | import {defineCliConfig} from 'sanity/cli'
    |                               ^
  2 | 
  3 | export default defineCliConfig({
  4 |   api: {
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

It's a project that uses Next.js, React, Tailwind CSS, and Sanity.io